# How to change the language of a button label in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Im trying to change the language for the label of the buttons. Currently it looks like this and I need to change it to english:

[image]

Comment: forever or onclick?

Comment: How is the language set/built currently for your app? We're going to need more than a picture, like a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the title property inside the button.

```
<button className="button" title="next-page"> Next page </button>
```